# Little Confused about the Microsoft Excel Interop Library

Tags: c#, excel

I know how to make new columns, I know how to add a header to that column, but I am a little unsure about adding values programatically.

I am going to be looping through rows and then adding values to the new columns that I create based on some functions I perform on the Data Set.  I thought a good way to start would be to just pick a row and loop through it and print out all the information in that row.  If I could figure out how to do that, I could probably right all the code necessary to loop through appropriate rows and get the data I need.  But I am a little confused about how to use this Range object...

```
    Range rng = (Range)wkSheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
```

Lets say I wanted to print out all the Range Row information to a console?  How would I loop through that Range and  print out that information?  Even change the information in the Range.  I know how to change the value of a single row, the header, but changing multiple rows is alluding me.

Comment: Uh does this mean your talking about MS Excel interop? You could make it much more clear in your title and question what exactly you are working with. Your chances of getting a answer would go up dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object[,] values = (object[,])rng.Value;
```

Probably duplicate [reading-from-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910400/reading-from-excel-range-into-multidimensional-array-c)