# C# how to iterate over excel columns

Tags: c#, excel

I want to get a specific column of an excel sheet and then iterate through it's cells. I want it to look something like this:

```
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(svDropPath);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet Name"];
var col = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns["C:C", Type.Missing]; // I want the 3rd column
foreach(Cell c in col)
....
```

How do I actually make this foreach loop?

Comment: Is the above code syntactically correct?

Comment: The foreach is not. That is exactly my question.. How do I iterate over the cells of a specific column (in my case I want the 3rd column)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop will looks as follow:

```
    foreach (Excel.Range item in col.Cells)
    {
        //whatever you want to do with your cells, here- msgbox of cells value
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(item.Value));
    }
```

Comment: You were faster than me :) Here you have a bit you missed: Excel.Range col = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns["C:C", Type.Missing];

Comment: To make things clearer. Also not sure if this code works without casting at all.

Comment: so if the column is the range then doesn't it mean I iterate over something else in the foreach loop which is not an Excel.Range ?

Comment: I think only slight correction is the casing in cells c is capital. col.Cells

Comment: @YonatanNir, i'm not sure if I get you right. If the column is range you could iterate through: columns (there will be one), rows (depending of the size of used range), cells (the same number as rows). Therefore you need to state `col.Cells` to inform compiler which collection you iterate.

Comment: `Cells` in `col` not found in the `foreach` for me. Any idea why?

Comment: how do you defined `var col` in your code? do you use `.UsedRange` or other property referring to range?

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no nice way of doing it other than to loop through the indices in question and use either Cells or Rows:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
  Range cell = col.Cells[i, 1];
  // or
  Range cell = col.Rows[i];
}
```

However, note that if you are reading and/or writing all the cells, you are much better off reading/writing the whole column to/from an array of object, and then looping through the array items, as outlined in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18058144/1737957 . Not only is this much faster, you can also use nicer language constructs for looping since you are now dealing with a straightforward C# array.

The only reason you would have to loop rather than do this AFAIK is if you were accessing something like conditional formats etc., rather than just cell contents, and you couldn't write a whole range of them in one statement. However there may be ways of doing these too using arrays.