# Accessing Excel file from Visual Studio VB application - performance issues

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm developing a simple VB application made of two parts:

- A Main (with a GUI form) receiving inputs and displaying outputs (very simple, really, and only needed to text the class described in the following),
- A Class with a single function (for now) that opens in read only an Excel file, updates some cells, and retrieves the value of a calculation for another cell.

The code of the Class follows:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Public Class MyClass

    Public Function Excel_Calculate(ByVal p_File_Reference, ByVal p_Sheet_Reference, ByVal p_In_Cells_Values, ByVal p_Result_Cell, ByRef p_Result, ByRef p_Result_Code)

        Console.WriteLine("    1 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Dim l_List_of_Inputs() As String
        Dim l_One_Cell_Address_Value() As String
        Dim l_Counter As Integer

        Console.WriteLine("    1.1 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Dim Excel_Application As Excel.Application = CreateObject("excel.application") ' EXPENSIVE!!!!

        Console.WriteLine("    1.2 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Dim Excel_Workbooks As Excel.Workbooks = Excel_Application.Workbooks

        Console.WriteLine("    1.3 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Dim Excel_Workbook As Excel.Workbook

        Console.WriteLine("    1.4 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Dim Excel_WorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        Console.WriteLine("    2 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)
        
        Dim l_One_Cell_Address As String
        Dim l_One_Cell_Value As Double

        Dim l_Return_Code As Integer

        Excel_Application.Visible = False

        Console.WriteLine("    3 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Excel_Workbook = Excel_Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Me\ABCD.xlsx", , True)

        Console.WriteLine("    4 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        Excel_WorkSheet = Excel_Workbook.ActiveSheet

        Console.WriteLine("    5 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)

        l_List_of_Inputs = Split(p_In_Cells_Values, ",")

        For l_Counter = 0 To l_List_of_Inputs.Length - 1

            l_One_Cell_Address_Value = Split(l_List_of_Inputs(l_Counter), ":")
            l_One_Cell_Address = l_One_Cell_Address_Value(0)
            l_One_Cell_Value = Convert.ToDouble(l_One_Cell_Address_Value(1))

            Excel_WorkSheet.Range(l_One_Cell_Address).Value = l_One_Cell_Value

        Next l_Counter

        Console.WriteLine("    6 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)


        If (Trim(Excel_WorkSheet.Range(p_Result_Cell).Value) <> "") Then
            p_Result = Excel_WorkSheet.Range(p_Result_Cell).Value
            l_Return_Code = 0

        Else
            l_Return_Code = 2000
        End If

        Excel_Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Excel_Workbook.Close()

        Excel_Application.Quit()

        Excel_Workbook = Nothing

        Console.WriteLine("    7 ----- " & Now & "." & Now.Millisecond)


        p_Result_Code = l_Return_Code

        Return 0

    End Function


End Class
```

Running this takes between 2 and 3 seconds (elapsed time) on a rather powerful machine. When doing the same directly within the Excel, the response time to the update of the INPUT cells is less than perceptible.

I added some prints (see the code) to find out where the main delays are, and the generated prints are:

```
    1   ----- 16/10/2017 14:15:59.209
    1.1 ----- 16/10/2017 14:15:59.209
    1.2 ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.354
    1.3 ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.388
    1.4 ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.388
    2   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.388
    3   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.389
    4   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.942
    5   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:00.970
    6   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:01.196
    7   ----- 16/10/2017 14:16:01.235
```

meaning that most of the time is consumed by:

1. Creating the application object (between 1.1 and 1.2 above, about 1.1 secs),
2. Opening the file (between 3 and 4 above, about 0.55 sec),
3. During the update of cells within the Excel (5 cells being updated; between 5 and 6 above, about 0.2 secs).

It is important to stress that this service **must** allow all pre-defined calculations within the Excel file to execute.

Why is this taking so long, and is there an alternative way to implement this functionality?

Comment: How comparable are steps 1 and 2 to the time it takes to manually launch Excel and open your file?

Comment: take a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373445/excel-work-book-read-from-c-sharp-substantially-slow)

Comment: @freginold, thanks for your response. I fully understand what you are saying, but there is a fundamental difference between the two scenarios: When accessing the Excel file from the code above, the normal user interface of Excel is disabled and, since I can't truly estimate the "weight" of this part, I cannot take this into account.

Comment: @Crashman, thank you for the feed. Unfortunately, it would appear that I'm missing something... My development is done within VISUAL STUDIO in VB. I don't see how I can use the OPEN XML library here. Could you provide some sample code (you could use the code I posted above of course). Thanks.

Comment: Does Excel have any add-ins that you could disable, that may speed the process up?

Comment: @freginold, I don't think so. It is a standard installation.