# Get DocumentText from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I need to get all document formatted text from an excel spreadsheet.

I need a better solution that this. This achieves my goal but does not scale at all!

```
StringBuilder strData = new StringBuilder();
var worksheets = ReferenceDocument.Worksheets;
foreach (Excel._Worksheet worksheet in worksheets)
{
    foreach (var cell in worksheet.UsedRange.Cast<Excel.Range>())
    {
        object value = cell.Text;
        string strValue = value == null ? null : value.ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue)) strData.AppendLine(strValue);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've tried calling worksheet.UsedRange.Text to get an array of strings, but unfortunately it returns System.DbNull and not an array.

Comment: You need to reduce the number of individual calls made between the two processes (C# and Excel).  Likely the best way to acheive this would be to read the entire `UsedRange` into an array and then process that array in .NET   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910400/reading-from-excel-range-into-multidimensional-array-c-sharp

Comment: Unfortunately calling range.Text results in returing System.DbNull

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in the Excel object model I could use. I solved issue by using OleDb

```
StringBuilder strData = new StringBuilder();
ReferenceDocument.SaveCopyAs(strSomeTempFile);
var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", strSomeTempFile);
var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    foreach(DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        string worksheetName = schemaRow["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
        string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheetName);
        var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            var value = row[col.ColumnName];
            if (!(value is System.DBNull)) strData.AppendLine(value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle error
    throw;
}
finally
{
    cnn.Close();
}
return strData;
```