# Reading From Excel File - Cells with Values Show Null

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have written some code that reads every row in an excel file (for two specific columns) which I will be using later to execute an update SQL Query for each of the rows with a value.

I have displayed these values in a listbox, and I am getting far more nulls than expected when comparing with the stock codes in the excel file.

I have tried changing the formatting of the excel file, but this did not make any difference. There are rows where there definitely are stock codes at that position, but when the program does the cell comparison the program identifies them as nulls when they actually have values.

Does anyone know what the problem is with my code?

```
private void btnStockCodes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string file = @"\\amn-fs-01\users$\Shanel\Desktop\Stock Codes.xlsx";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(file);
    Worksheet ews = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1];
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range usedRange = ews.UsedRange;

    int TotalCounter = 0;
    string StockCode = "";
    string ReserveID = "";
    int nullcounter = 0;
    int foundcounter = 0;

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
    {
        StockCode = "";
        ReserveID = "";
        TotalCounter = TotalCounter + 1;

        if (row.Cells[TotalCounter,7].Value == null)
        {
            Listbox1.Items.Add(TotalCounter + " null");
            nullcounter = nullcounter + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            StockCode = row.Cells[TotalCounter,7].Value.ToString();
            ReserveID = row.Cells[TotalCounter, 3].Value.ToString();
            Listbox1.Items.Add(TotalCounter + " " + StockCode + " " + ReserveID);
            foundcounter = foundcounter + 1;
        }
    }

    txtTotal1.Text = foundcounter.ToString() + " Found";
    txtTotal2.Text = nullcounter.ToString() + " Null Values";
    txtTotal3.Text = TotalCounter.ToString() + " Total Records";
}
```

Comment: Please upload a sample file for us to test the code on. Feel free to cut it down to just a few lines of data that show the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  I have added a dropbox link to an example of the excel file in the description.

Answer (score 1):

I would not trust that Worksheet.UsedRange always works correctly, sometimes it contains more cells than it should, or less. My suggestion is to read all rows in worksheet, while you have any values. Once there are no more values, just stop reading it.
And if you have too many rows, you can read all values at the same time into an array, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/910433/1295010) and work with the array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your contributions, I have resolved the error!

It occurs in the row.Cells[TotalCounter,7].Value.ToString()

It should have been row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()

There was no need for me to specify a row index as that's taken care of in the Foreach loop. I will look into alternative ways of writing the code as Worksheet.UsedRange might not work in all cases as Alex suggested.