# How to retrieve efficiently all strings from a large Excel documents

Tags: c#, .net, excel

The Excel spreadsheet should be read by .NET. It is very efficient to read all values from the active range by using the property `Value`. This transfers all values in a two dimensional array, by one single call to Excel.

However reading strings is not possible for a range which contains more than one single cell. Therefor we have to iterate over all cells and use the `Text` property. This shows very poor performance for larger document.

The reason of using strings rather than values is to obtains the correct format (for instance for dates or the number of digits).

Here is a sample code written in C# to demonstrate the approach.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    var worksheet = xlApp.ActiveSheet;
    var cells = worksheet.UsedRange();

    // read all values in array -> fast
    object[,] arrayValues = cells.Value;

    // create array for text of the same extension
    object[,] arrayText = (object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object),
        new int[] { arrayValues.GetUpperBound(0), arrayValues.GetUpperBound(1) },
        new int[] { arrayValues.GetLowerBound(0), arrayValues.GetLowerBound(1) });

    // read text for each cell -> slow
    for (int row = arrayValues.GetUpperBound(0); row <= arrayValues.GetUpperBound(0); ++row)
    {
        for (int col = arrayValues.GetUpperBound(0); col <= arrayValues.GetUpperBound(1); ++col)
        {
            object obj = cells[row, col].Text;
            arrayText[row, col] = obj;
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, if there is a more efficient way to read the complete string content from an Excel document. One idea was to use `cells.Copy` to copy the content to the clipboard to get it from there. However this has some restrictions and could of course interfere with users which are working with the clipboard at the same time. So I wonder if there are better approaches to solve this performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below:

```
using (MSExcel.Application app = MSExcel.Application.CreateApplication()) 
{
    MSExcel.Workbook book1 = app.Workbooks.Open( this.txtOpen_FilePath.Text);
    MSExcel.Worksheet sheet = (MSExcel.Worksheet)book1.Worksheets[1];
    MSExcel.Range range = sheet.GetRange("A1", "F13");

    object value = range.Value; //the value is boxed two-dimensional array
}
```

The code is provided from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/910433/5137920). It should be much more efficient than your code, but may not be the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you check my explanation and my example above you will see that I'm using the range.Value. However this does not bring the format. So if you are using doubles you don't know the number of digits. If you are using date/time, you don't get the format etc.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I don't know a better way to do that, but I will search, and if I find any, let you know.